# Prove that if $ (x+y)$ is even, then $(x−y)$ is even, for integers. Did I prove correctly? is this a direct proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, solution-verification

For $x+y$ to be even, either $x$ and $y$ are both even, or $x$ and $y$ are both odd.

If $x$ and $y$ are both even we obtain: $x=2k$ and $y=2j$.
substituting into $x-y$ we get $2k-2j$.
$2(k-j)$ is even, so we have proved the first case.

Now if $x$ and $y$ are both odd, we obtain: $x=2k+1$ and $y=2j+1$.
substituting into $x-y$ we get $(2k+1)-(2j+1)$,
$2k+1-2j-1= 2k-2j= 2(k-j)$ which is even, and we have proved the remaining case.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!! This for sure is NOT a direct proof. See the Wikipedia article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_proof It says: "[...] In order to directly prove a conditional statement of the form "If p, then q", **it suffices to consider the situations in which the statement p is true.** [...]". You have not used your hypothesis ($x+y$ is even), however it is a valid proof.

Comment: "either x and y are both even, or x and y are both odd."  Why?  If I'm not going to accept the conjecture as obvious I'm not going to accept this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can have a direct proof that $x+y$ and $x-y$ have the same parity, since $(x+y)-(x-y)=2y$ is even.

Comment: but did i fail to prove x+y is even then x-y is even?

Comment: Not at all. It is quite correct, but a bit long in my opinion.

Comment: It is correct again, but it is shorter if you  remark that $x+y,\:(x+y)^2 $  and $x^2+y^2$ have the same parity.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof (by cases) is correct, but you could do simpler without considering cases: if $x+y = 2q$, then $x-y = (x+y)-2y = 2q - 2y$ so $x-y = 2(q-y)$, which means that $x-y$ is even.

Comment: NOTE: i am proving something different: is this proof also correct?**Prove that if x^2+y^2 is even then x+y is even.** assume x+y is odd. if x+y is odd, then either x is odd and y is even, or x is even and y is odd, either way we obtain: 2j+(2k+1) now, substituting into x^2+y^2 we get (2j)^2+(2k+1)^2 this becomes: 4j^2+4k^2+4k+1 we obtain 2(2j^2+2k^2+2k)+1, which by definition is odd. we have therefore shown that if x+y is odd then x^2+y^2 is odd, so by contraposition f x^2+y^2 is even then x+y is even

Answer (score 0):

Note that if the difference between $p^2$ and $q^2$ is a multiple of $4,$ then $p$ and $q$ must be of equal parity, for otherwise, we have wlog that $(2m+1)^2-(2n)^2=(2m+1-2n)(2m+1+2n)=(2M+1)(2N+1),$ which is never even.

Now since $(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2=4xy,$ it follows that $x+y$ and $x-y$ are of equal parity, and in particular if one of them is even then the other must be as well.